# Sort by a function that takes argument(s) in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write a function to sort a vector of custom class objects by a variety of different attributes.

The c++ sort reference, found here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Says that you can sort like this:

```
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);
```

What I would like to be able to do is pass an argument to myfunction in addition to the two objects from my vector like this:

```
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction(mode=7));
```

Do you know of a way to do so?

I am relatively new to c++, coming from python where this would be easy.

Comment: How do you use `mode`?

Comment: Correction, the [`std::sort()` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: What does `mode=7` mean? How would you implement this in [tag:python]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a functor instead of a free function:

```
struct Functor{
  int mode;
  bool operator() (int a,int b) { return (a<b);}
} functor;
```

The overloaded `()` operator executes when the functor is called by `sort`. In there you can have a variable `mode` and use it as you need.
Then set mode (you could also set in on the functor constructor) and call `sort` using it:

```
functor.mode = 7; // or set it in the constructor
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), functor);
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about functors. They seem useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C++11, you can use a lambda:

```
sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), [] (Type a, Type b) { return myfunction(a,b,7); });
```

Comment: If you're not using C++11, `boost::bind` is basically compatible with `std::bind`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a functor:

```
struct MyFunction {
  bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { /* implement logic here */ }
  int mode;
};
```

Then pass an instance of that instead of your plain function `myfunction`. Here, `T` is the type used to instantiate your `std::vector`.

```
MyFunction f;
f.mode = 7;
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), f);
```

If you have C++11 support, you can use a lambda function:

```
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](const T&a, const T& b) { /* implement*/ });
```